# simdjson c++ parser - how to extract number of array elements

Tags: c++, json

I am using simdjson C++ parser.

Suppose I have code like this:

```
#include "simdjson.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace simdjson;

int main(void) {
    ondemand::parser parser;
    auto json = "  { \"number\": [ 40, 39, 37, 40 ] }"_padded;

    ondemand::document test  = parser.iterate(json);

    std::vector<int64_t> parsedNumbers;    //! How many elements in json to initialize?
    // std::vector<int64_t> parsedNumbers ( number_of_elements_in_json)

    for (const int64_t number: test.find_field("number"))
    {
        parsedNumbers.push_back(number);
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`number` array contains 4 elements in this case, but in the next json it could be 10000.

I would like to ensure that the std::vector has appropriate capacity at the start and not relocating in the loop (when number of elements are more than actual capacity).

Is it even possible? How to extract number of elements from json array?

Answer (score 0):

The `ondemand::array` does not have a size method.

You can (but should not!) use `std::distance` and the `begin()` and `end()` methods. But this is O(n)! And it consumes the iterable-array (i.e. you'd have to jump back in the document to then read it in a second step).

You don't say why you want to `reserve()` before you do your extraction. But I suppose it is due to performance. If it is, measure both ways and compare.

---

The `simdjson::dom::array` has a `size()` method.

https://simdjson.org/api/0.9.1/classsimdjson_1_1dom_1_1array.html#a698f2f984d1a78a68962c06b2f047686

Comment: But this is different array? My code uses ondemand namespace, so I got this array

https://simdjson.org/api/0.9.1/classsimdjson_1_1_s_i_m_d_j_s_o_n___i_m_p_l_e_m_e_n_t_a_t_i_o_n_1_1ondemand_1_1array.html?fbclid=IwAR3APK6Miic7eJJTrv7DFgdEV_DJ5SgUKInbsRwi0BfcVQ3J5neKNMSKV3g

I do not see size() method there

Comment: That's what I originally wrote. The history didn't get saved (probably b/c I updated answer quickly after first post). Anyway, updated again. TLDR: Don't `reserve()`.

Comment: I created issue on simdjson github. The author responded that the "size" functionality is going to be added.

Issue created: https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/issues/1574

Pull request: https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/pull/1577